# Change socialize template color

Tags: templates, fix-my-code, t3-framework

I want to change the menu background color of [Joomla socialize template](http://socialize.jomsocial.com/). When i open my site on mobile the top menu bar seems to be in white color. I want to change the color to 365190 
socialnetwork.silkroutegemsinc.com Anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: can you please tell us what css you are using currently to achieve this? So, that we can guide you better

Comment: I want to use 365190 color in the footer background. I am using socialize template with t3 plugin. Link is given below. www.socialnetwork.silkroutegemsinc.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the link provided by you, simple add the below css code in your template.css or your custom css:

`.t3-footer {
    background: #365190;
}`

Hope this helps you

Comment: No its not working over here

Comment: Where have you added it? Have you also cleared the cache?

Comment: i have added this code under template.css and cleared the cache and refresh the browser also but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: @AmiraliPanjwani try putting important to it as follows: `background: #365190 !important;`  Let me know if this helps

Comment: I tried your instructions but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: I can provide you the access if you wish.

Comment: @AmiraliPanjwani : I had a look here in the link you gave me : http://www.socialnetwork.silkroutegemsinc.com/ and I can see the css is displaying on top of the page. This is wrong. I guess you have added in the wrong place. Please add it properly or add in your custom css

Comment: @AmiraliPanjwani refer this: https://www.joomlart.com/forums/topic/t3-blank-template-change-the-footer-color/

Comment: i think you forget to add `<style>.t3-footer {
    background: #365190;
}</style>` tag

Comment: I have creat a “custom.css” file in: “…/templates/t3_blank/css/” Then type this code: .t3-footer {
background: [URL=http://www.joomlart.com/forums/usertag.php?do=list&action=hash&hash=FF0000]#FF0000[/URL]
}  but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: @AmiraliPanjwani I checked your custom.css file and this is a wrong way of adding css. Remove what you have written in `custom.css` and simply copy `.t3-footer { background: #365190 !important; }` and paste it in `custom.css`. This will work. Let us know if it works

Comment: {Ruchika]  Thanks i have followed your instructions and it worked for me.

Comment: great :) I am glad it worked for you